# Then is not a function when method returns nothing - Javascript

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to create a method, and in another method to access its return.
However, when I don't return anything, the promise gives the error: then is not a function.

```js
verifyUser() {
  if (currentUser.Title) {
    return Promise.resolve(currentUser)
  }
}

myMethod() {
  this.verifyUser
    .then(user => {
      console.log(user);
    })
}
```

When nothing returns, I tried to catch it, but it didn't work either

Comment: Does that not make sense? Undefined isn't a promise, it doesn't have then or catch props.

Comment: var promise = verify(); Its missing the parenthesis

Comment: `However, when I don't return anything, the promise gives the error: then is not a function.` _Which_ promise? When you don't return anything, there __is__ no promise to call `then` on.

Comment: What should `verifyUser` do in the case when `currentUser` does not have `Title`. Throw an error, return `null`, … ?

Comment: Can you elaborate? The code you've shown is wrong

Comment: in verifyUser, if you don't go inside the IF, the function does not return anything... Please, rewrite your code

Comment: The way you're using `verifyUser`, it needs to always return a promise. So within `verifyUser` you need an `else` that  either returns a promise with a different fulfillment value, or returns a rejected promise.

Comment: let promise = this.verifyUser(); if (promise) promise.then() ...

Comment: If you're going to use `.then()` on the return value of that function, you  have to make sure that the function ALWAYS returns a promise.  The code you show sometimes returns a promise and sometimes returns `undefined`.  It should be pretty clear why that doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct version of your code should be something like this:

```
function verifyUser() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (currentUser.Title) {
      resolve(currentUser);
    } else{
      reject();
    }
  });
}

function myMethod() {
  verifyUser()
    .then(user => {
      console.log(user);
    })
    .catch(() => {});
}
```

Comment: Using `Promise.resolve()`  and `Promise.reject()` would be better though

Comment: If `verifyUser()` has no async code, then why even use a promise at all?

Comment: No, but It's just a brief version! and show the main code structure. assuming there is lots of works to do in methods ...